# How do I access an object from the main process from a render process [Electron]

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to create a tool for editing files containing a object that is related to my companies business logic.  I'm using electron to do so.

I've created a javascript class which represents the object, handles its internals, and provides buisness functions on it:

```
class Annotation {
    constructor() {
        this._variables = []
        this._resourceGenerators = []
    }

    get variables() {
        return this._variables
    }

    get resourceGenerators() {
        return this._resourceGenerators
    }

    save(path) {
        ...
    }

    static load(path) {
        ...
    }
};

module.exports = Annotation;
```

I create the object in my main process, and I have an event handler which gives render processes access to it:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
const Annotation = require('./annotation.js');

... Do electron window stuff here ...

var annotation = new Annotation()

ipcMain.on('getAnnotation', (event, path) => {

    event.returnValue = annotation
})
```

I've just found out that sending an object through ipcMain.sendSync uses JSON.stringify to pass the annotation, meaning it looses the getters/functions on it.

I'm fairly new to web/electron development; what is the proper way of handling this?  Previously I had handlers in main for dealing with most of the functions that the render processes needed, but main started to become very bloated, so I'm trying to refactor it somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

**TL; DR: RECONSTRUCT OBJECT ON RECEIVER SIDE.**

Description: Electron's main architectural design is based on multi-process, separating main (node.js) and each renderer (chromium) processes and allow to communicate between processes via IPC mechanism. And due to several reason (efficiency, performance, security, etcs) Electron's OOTO IPC only allows serializable POJO to be sent / received. Once receiver have those data, you may need reconstruct desired object from there.

If your intention around `access` is to share references like true singleton, that's not available.

Comment: Is there any sort of pattern for recreating the object in the render process (e.g. passing it into a constructor)?  Or do I just create a function which adds functions to instances of Annotation, and then call that from the constructor/render process?

Comment: It's up to your usecases. There are several way to achieve in js, and based on code design some might be better or not.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would suggest is that in most cases, you don't need to transfer anything to the main process. The main process is mostly for creating windows and accessing Electron API's which are restricted to the main process. Everything else should and can be done from the renderer including access to all node modules. You can write files, access databases, etc all from the renderer.

Read [this article](https://codeburst.io/deep-dive-into-electrons-main-and-renderer-processes-7a9599d5c9e2) about the differences between the main and renderer processes and what you should be using each for.

Comment: I read somewhere that the main process should be used for any slow tasks, so to avoid the render process slowing?

Comment: If you read that anywhere it's wrong! If you read the linked article it explains why. The main process marshals IPC between the renderers and GPU process so blocking there can actually hang all the renderers too.

Comment: Ok so I read that article, but now I'm even more confused.  So the thing I'm editing is essentially a file.  I have html/js for viewing it, and a separate html/js for editing each type of object within it.  I don't want to save the file when I transition pages, how do I pass it from one render thread to the other?